# how can we decrypting 128 bit AES encrypted text in php with cipher mode ECB and padding mode PKCS7

Tags: php, aes

i fetched such problem in my project

how can we decrypting 128 bit AES encrypted text in php  with cipher mode ECB and padding mode PKCS7

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use [mcrypt](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/ref.mcrypt.php).

But may I ask why you're encrypting with ECB mode at all? Remember the [known problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29) with that?

Comment: yeah i know but its desire of my client

Answer (score 1):

```
mcrypt_decrypt('rijndael-128', $key, $data, 'ecb');
```

You will have to manually remove [the padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29#Byte_padding).